# Xbox 360 HDD Saved Games Recovery

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

Yesterday, I was playing Worms 2 when my Xbox 360 froze and I had restart, when I did all content of my 250GB HD was showing as damaged, when I restarted again, all content where gone and said that I need to format my HD. I removed the HDD from my xbox and plugged on my PC. I want to recover my save files (got saves since 2014).

## Recovery Tools (Windows)

### Random softwares

I used two random recovery softwares and managed to get some files, whatever most of files are unusable .zip files:

[image: zip_files]

### FatXplorer

I also tryied a tool named fatxplorer, which recognized the HDD, but were unable to read it, the error message is in Portuguese, and says "the request could not be performed due to an I/O device error".

[image]

## Recovery Tools (Linux)

In my linux OS, I've used `testdisk`, `photorec`, `dosfsck`, `gparted` and `smartctl` to try to get any information. I got the following data:

- My disk **does not has a partition**
- **all space is showing as unallocated**
- None of the tools could identify the **filesystem**

Please, help me =(